# Can't handle Error in React-Native-Firebase SMS Confirmation function

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I'm Using React-Native-Firebase for Phone Authentication for one of my React Native Project.

followed this [Phone Auth Documentation](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/auth/phone-auth) and every thing works fine.

```
try {
  await confirmation.confirm('12345'); // User entered code
  // Successful login - onAuthStateChanged is triggered
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e); // Invalid code
}
```

When I tried to enter wrong verification for handling Error I can't able to catch the error in console, Instead I'm getting the Error Screen

[image]

Here is my actual code

```
  const submitAuth = async () => {
    try {
      authLoader(true);
      await params.confirmation.confirm(smsCode);
      // Successful login - onAuthStateChanged is triggered
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e); // Can't able to catch the Error
    }
  };
```

also tried replacing async function with **.then().catch** function still getting the same.

Is that am I missing something ?